# How to truncate the name title on related products block magento

Tags: magento2, php

```
  <div class="product-item-details">
                            <strong class="product-item-name">
                                <a title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($item->getName()) ?>"
                                   href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($item)) ?>"
                                   class="product-item-link">
                                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($item->getName()) ?>
                                </a>
```

I'm trying to use substr like this

`substr($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'),0,75)`

But my code does not work correctly, it shows a 504 on product page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are using $_product while in the code you pasted product seems to be $item

Try changing:

`substr($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'),0,75)`

To

`substr($_helper->productAttribute($item, $item->getName() , 'name'),0,75)`

Comment: Thanks works perfectly